# FTP: The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftp-client

I have a VB.Net Application (Console Application) Which is copying files from FTP Server

When I'm using this application on windows 7 or 8 it works well and copy all the files

but when using the application on windows server 2003 it returns error on response:

The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation

what should i do to avoid this error ?
is the issue is on the environment (Windows Server 2003) ?